# How to set a hint in Edit Text with different color.for example Hint* and * contain only red color

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set a hint on edit text the color of one character in hint is red.
For  example Hint*

Here color of * is Red.

```
// go is TextInputEditText 

String colorText= "Hint"
                + "<font color=\"#E72A02\"><bold>"
                + "*"
                + "</bold></font>"
               ;

      go.setHint(Html.fromHtml(colorText));
```

By using this code I am able to do that but there is few cases happen with that code which I mention below.

1. one problem the text is not animated because it set in
   TextInputEditText Dynamically.
2. if I use this code on TextInputLayout (i.e go is TextInputLayout) than the color of hint does not effect.

Comment: Currently, that's not really possible with `TextInputLayout`, AFAIK. Last I looked, its helper class that handles that floating hint draws the text as a flat `String`, with a simple `Canvas#drawText()` call

Comment: Did you tried spannable string ?

Comment: spannable string not working.